# Не работает импортированная функция

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

У меня не работает импортированая функция.
file1.js

```js
module.exports.die = function die() {
throw new Error("Script stopped");
}
```

file2.js

```js
var di = require("./file1");
di.die();
```

Ошибка:

```bsh
TypeError: di.die is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты немного не так делал экспортирование, первый файл у тебя будет выглядеть вот так

```
module.exports = {
    die: function() {
        throw new Error("this is error")
    }
}
```

а второй

```
let di = require("./1.js");
di.die();
```

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: как ты запускаешь скрипт, и ты переименовал file1.js в 1.js, я у себя смотрел все работает

Comment: Запускаю я скрипт командой node bot.js. нет, я не переименовал файл. Так же при выводе в консоль переменной di я получаю это ``` {} ```

Comment: у меня 2 файла 1.js и 2.js , сделай так же и напиши в консоль node js/2.js "js" перед скриптом я написал так как у меня они лежат в папке js

Comment: Странно. Так у меня все работает.

Comment: ничего странного, ты просто работал с файлами которых нет. Если решение помогло отметь ответ как решение